# Plotting multiple lines in one chart but next to each other using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following quarterly df.

```
group date          share
A     2018-03-31    0.03
A     2018-06-30    0.03
A     2018-09-30    0.03
A     2018-12-31    0.02
A     2019-03-31    0.02
B     2018-03-31    0.04
B     2018-06-30    0.04
B     2018-09-30    0.05
B     2018-12-31    0.06
B     2019-03-31    0.07
C     2018-03-31    0.05
C     2018-06-30    0.06
C     2018-09-30    0.07
C     2018-12-31    0.07
C     2019-03-31    0.09
```

UPDATE

i used the code suggested below

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
df.set_index(['group'], append=True).unstack()['share'].plot(ax=ax)
ax.set(xticks=np.arange(0,len(df)))
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
ax.set_xticklabels(df.date.dt.to_period('Y').astype(str).values, rotation = 45)
ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)
plt.ylim(0, 0.22)
plt.show()
```

I have this overlapping x-axis ticks. How can i only have the start and the end year for each group?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As your dates are repeating but you do not want the lines on top of one another, you will need to plot the data as you have done above and then change the tick labels so that the dates show up. See if this is what you are looking for... Note that I have plotted with the limited data you have provided.

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
df.set_index('group', append=True).unstack()['share'].plot(ax=ax)
ax.set(xticks=np.arange(0,len(df)))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.date.astype(str).values, rotation = 45)
ax.grid(None)
```

[image]

**UPDATED**

Hi - Based on your new requirement, I have added some code to the above one. Once you have the above plot built, you can edit it like this to pick the labels you need. Remember to add this to the bottom of the already present code.... Hope this satisfies you first-last label requirement.

```
# First, take the existing dataframe and get the min and max date for each group - A,B,C
df1=df.groupby('group').agg({'date':['min', 'max']}).reset_index() #Get max & min
df1.columns=df1.columns.get_level_values(1) #Remove multi-index
df1=df1.rename(columns={'':'group'}) #Rename for easy identification
labels=pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['group'], value_vars=['min', 'max']).sort_values('group')['value']  #Melt and sort to get the min, max dates for each group
labels = [date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for date_obj in labels]  #Convert to str

## Secondly, read each label, see if in labels array and show, else hide
new_labels = []
for lab in ax.get_xticklabels():  #Get each label from labels array (Min or Max)
    txt = lab.get_text()
    if txt in labels:
        new_labels.append(txt) # append if in labels list
    else:    
        new_labels.append("")  #Blank otherwise

ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels) # Set labels

ax.grid(None)
```

[image]

Comment: almost! i have a longer timeperiod so i get overlapping dates.  How do i make it so that i only get the first date and the last date for each group?

Comment: updated code to show only max and min values for each group